# How to cover image/text with another one

Tags: html, css

I am new in CSS and HTML but I creating website where I need to cover text or picture with another one. I made example in Photoshop what exactly I need:

[image: Expected]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: For text you can try `text-shadow`, For an image use it as a background and use a hidden child element which inherits the background image and show it on hover.

Comment: @Zohir Salak thank you

Comment: Also you can use z-index to cover image with different images. 
[More info about z-index](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**A solution based on css shadow:**

```css
h1 {
  font-family: cursive;
  text-shadow: -10px -10px 0px rgba(150, 150, 150, 1);
}
```

```html
<h1>Lorem Ipsum<h1>
```

Online tools like : https://css3gen.com/text-shadow/ could help you to construct right `text-shadow` property